# How do I send data between Ajax and RestController in a SpringBoot?

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I want to send the data I received by Ajax to the RestController with POST method and process it there. Then I want to return the list that will be created as a result of the transaction to Ajax.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {

    @GetMapping("/web")
    public String web()
    {
        return "fake";
    }
}
```

**Fake.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(function () {
                $("#ajaxselect1").on('change', function () {
                    var selectedValue1 = $("select[name=ajaxselect1]").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url :  "/ajaxrest",
                        data: {item: selectedValue1},
                        success : function(data){
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>AJAX TESTING</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <select name="ajaxselect1" id="ajaxselect1" class="form-control" >
            <option value="Chose" selected>Chose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
public class AjaxRest {

    @PostMapping("/ajaxrest")
public String testAjaxPost(@RequestParam("item") String item) {

        if(item.equals("1")){

            List<String> cars = new ArrayList<>();
            cars.add("bugatti");
            cars.add("ferrari");
            cars.add("honda");
            cars.add("mercedes");

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return "hello-world!";
}

}
```

When I'm not sending any data, Chrome Console returns this information to me:

**Chrome Console Error**

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:7070/ajaxrest 404
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   web:26
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
y.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
ListPicker._handleWindowTouchEnd
```

`POST` method does not work. How do I run it with `POST` method? How do I send data between `Ajax` and `RestController`?

Answer (score 0):

What exact AJAX error you are getting ? As your if loop looks good, but this might help,

```
@RestController
public class AjaxRest {

    @PostMapping("/ajaxrest")
    public Object testAjaxPost(@RequestBody String item) {

        if(item.equals("1")){

            //If the incoming data is 1, I want to send this list to Ajax.
            List<String> cars = new ArrayList<>();
            cars.add("bugatti");
            cars.add("ferrari");
            cars.add("honda");
            cars.add("mercedes");
           // Send list of cars 
           return cars;

        }
else{
// Your business logic
return "your_value";
}

    }

}
```

Comment: The `GET` method works fine, but the `POST` method does not work. It's turning back the error in `console`.